# Connect-MsolService non-interactive

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365, azure-powershell

I been working on one script which connects to msolservice and do some management activities. However, I am trying to save the password in Azure KeyVault and retrieve the password from there. However, its prompting a authentication. It shouldn't be interactive. Here is my code, what could go wrong here. Below identity is excluded in MFA.

```
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $TenantId -ServicePrincipal -Subscription $AzurekeyvSubscriptionId
Set-AzContext -Subscription $AzurekeyvSubscriptionId -ErrorAction Stop
$SecurePassword = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVaultName -Name svc-np-notify-passwd).SecretValueText
$SecurePassword2 = ConvertTo-SecureString $SecurePassword -asplaintext -force

# Retrieve credential from Automation asset store and authenticate to Azure AD
$username = "azuser-abc@abc.onmicrosoft.com"
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $SecurePassword2
$O365Cred = Get-Credential $cred
Connect-msolservice -Credential $O365Cred
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you run `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret`, it requires you firstly sign in with `Connect-AzAccount`.

If you don't run `Connect-AzAccount`, you won't get the value for `$SecurePassword`, which leads you to have a null value for password of `$cred`.

So when you run your script, `$O365Cred = Get-Credential $cred` will ask you to manually enter your credentials.

The root cause is that you have not set a password for it at all. So since you want to get the password from the key vault, you should log in first.

If you don't want to sign in interactively, you can consider sign in with a service principal. See [Example 3: Connect to Azure using a service principal account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-6.0.0#example-3--connect-to-azure-using-a-service-principal-account).

And you should [Assign a Key Vault access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal) to the service principal to allow it to read your key vault.

---

**UPDATE:**

`(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'Contoso' -Name 'ITSecret').SecretValueText` has been removed from the official sample in the latest Azure Powershell module version.

So your `$SecurePassword` is null.

Please use the following script to get `$SecurePassword`.

```
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVaultName -Name svc-np-notify-passwd
$SecurePassword = '';
$ssPtr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secret.SecretValue)
try {
    $SecurePassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($ssPtr)
} finally {
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($ssPtr)
}
$SecurePassword2 = ConvertTo-SecureString $SecurePassword -asplaintext -force
```